# Editing model ForeignKey as inline in Django administration?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Let's imagine that we have the following Django sample models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = model.CharField(max_length=64)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, blank=True, null=True)


class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

In the Django administration, field `A.b` is going to be represented as a dropdown widget with controls for adding new `B` instance, editing it and deleting.

I would like to show the `B` model similar to the way inlines are shown. However, to show inlines we need a foreign key relation from `B.a` to `A`. And I do not want to introduce such relation.

Is it possible to represent `B` in the `A` model admin page, as an inline?

Comment: `A` can only ever foreignkey to 1 of `B` so why would you need an inline?

Comment: Yes, it is only one. I need an inline because it is more graphically appealing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tool - https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2032/

A module that implements "reverse inlines" for this
use case.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know which B model are linked to concrete A model (reverse query), you can do:

```
b = B.objects.get(id=any_id)
a = b.a_set.all()
```

Then you can manage it, as you wish.

Comment: Yeah, in terms of models, I know how to access the related objects. My question is more related to the administration interface.