# In Django, How to Make Parent Object's Field Show and Editable on His Children's Admin Changelist Page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Let's say we have two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ForiegnkeyField(Author)
```

How to make Author's first_name and last_name field editable on Book Model's changelist page?

inline doesn't help here, because I want to edit parent object's field on his children's Admin Changelist view, not Changeform view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing model ForeignKey as inline in Django administration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248336/editing-model-foreignkey-as-inline-in-django-administration)

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks, but I want to edit Foreign Object's field in Django Admin Changelist view, not Changeform view.